# How to open different videos when clicking on different links?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 or more links. I want relevant videos to show up when users click on different links.

```
<video id="myVideo" width="1000" height="800" controls autoplay loop>

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<a onclick="myFunction('VideoConsonants/b.mp4')" style="text-decoration:none">b</a>

<a onclick="myFunction('VideoConsonants/p.mp4')" style="text-decoration:none">p</a>

//there are more links here...//

<script> 
function myFunction(str) { 
  document.getElementById("myVideo").src = str;
  document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
} 
</script>
```

But it didn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: Where your element contains the link in the above block code?

Comment: Works for me on Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/hLobanux/. Maybe the problem is how you are referencing your videos.

Comment: @ecg8, I tried your code but no video showed up

Comment: @ecg8, I sed your link (https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AdeptEarlyBarebirdbat-mobile.mp4) but nothing shoed up

Comment: @ecg8, I fixed, your code work, I got "href=#" in the onclick & that is why it didn't work. Thanks a lot!